# The SCALED flag in pygame's display.set_mode function has no effect

Tags: pygame, pygame2

I'm using [pygame](https://www.pygame.org) (version 2.0.0) to visualize big matrices interactively. I use pygame's [display.set_mode](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/display.html#pygame.display.set_mode) function to which I pass the `SCALED` flag in order to automatically scale-down the displayed image to fit the screen:

```
image = # a numpy 2D-array
surface = pygame.display.set_mode(image.shape, flags=pygame.SCALED)
```

Then, inside the event loop, I create a [surfarray](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surfarray.html) that resembles the numpy array, and render it using the [blit](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.blit) function:

```
surfarray = pygame.surfarray.make_surface(image)
surface.blit(surfarray, (0, 0))
```

However, the `SCALED` parameter doesn't seem to work, and pygame's window has the same size as the original image (which, in particular, is much bigger than the desktop size). Am I using the `SCALED` parameter wrong?

Comment: According to [this example](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/dac5b2e49613670f4c59ee7db06f2830e6e090ff/examples/setmodescale.py), `SCALED scales up the window for you`. They also use the `RESIZABLE` flag in conjunction. Maybe it only scales things up? Or you could try combining that flag with `RESIZABLE` and see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this example](https://github.com/pygame/pygame/blob/dac5b2e49613670f4c59ee7db06f2830e6e090ff/examples/setmodescale.py), `SCALED` scales up the window for you. They also use the `RESIZABLE` flag in conjunction. Maybe it only scales things up? Or you could try combining that flag with `RESIZABLE` and see if that works.